# Does a one pass solution exist in a problem of sorting an array containing only 0s, 1s, 2s, and 3s?

Tags: arrays, sorting, kadanes-algorithm

This is a typical problem requiring you to solve it in one-pass. You are given an array containing only 0s, 1s, and 2s. You are required to sort the array in one pass in O(1) auxiliary space. I was wondering if such one pass solutions exist for arrays containing more distinct values, and what is the limit of a number of distinct values to which one pass solutions exist.

Comment: *ANY* fixed number is O(1).  You just need a counter for each distinct value, initialized to zero; use them to count the values in the input, and then use them to output that many copies of the value.

Comment: @jasonharper: the counters need to be large enough to count up to the size of the input, so they actually require O(log n) space...

Comment: @ChrisDodd if you use this complexity rule, then the loop index by itself already requires O(log n) space. By the same rule, adding two integers is also O(log n).

Comment: @RaymondChen I beg to differ; adding two integers is O(n). Where n is the length of the input.

Comment: You can easily expand your solution for 3 values 0,1,2 to *k* values 0,1,...,*k*-1. This gives you an O(*k*)-space solution. If *k* = O(1), then this O(*k*)-space solution is an O(1)-space solution.